# Dynamic Form and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.7

I have a form for a `Serveur` Entity in which I have a dynamic part : I can add as many `typesDetails` I want :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //...
        ->add('typesDetails', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new LienServTypeDetailType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true))
    ;
}
```

with some Javascript in my view :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $container = $('div#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails');
        var $addLink = $('<a href="#" id="add_type" class="">Ajouter un type</a>');
        $container.append($addLink);
        $addLink.click(function(e) {
            addSource($container);
            e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
            return false;
        });

        var index = $container.find(':input').length;

        if (index == 0) {
            addSource($container);
        } else {
            $container.children('div').each(function() {
                addDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        }

        function addSource($container) {
            var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'type n°' + (index+1))
                .replace(/__name__/g, index));

            addDeleteLink($prototype);

            $container.append($prototype);

            index++;
        }

        function addDeleteLink($prototype) {
           $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');

            $prototype.append($deleteLink);

            $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
                $prototype.remove();
                e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

this part is OK.

But in my `typesDetails` form, I also need javascript to have 1 field based on another one (I used Symfony doc) :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('type')
    ;

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, TypeServeur $type = null) {
        $details = null === $type ? array() : $type->getDetailTypes();

        $form->add('detailType', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:DetailTypeServeur',
            'placeholder' => '-- Choisir un detail --',
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => $details,
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            if($data)
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getType());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('type')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $zone = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $zone);
        }
    );
}
```

And then you're suppose to add Javascript in the view with something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $zone = $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_4_type');
    $zone.change(function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');

        var data = {};
        data[$zone.attr('name')] = $zone.val();

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_4_detailType').replaceWith(
                    $(html).find('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_1_detailType')
                );
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

In this Javascript, there is a '4'. It was for a test (it's actually working for div n°4 ^^), but here the '4' need to be "dynamic" for each `typesDetails` I add. ex :

```
    var $zone = $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_1_type');
    var $zone = $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_2_type');
    var $zone = $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_3_type');
    var $zone = $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_4_type');
    ...
```

How am I suppose to do this ?

Comment: Help, I'm close but here I am ^^'

Comment: Do you have an online version?

Comment: I'm not sure of your problem, but It seem you need to perform a foreach on each zone. something like this:

Comment: $('div#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails>div').each(function(){  $zone.change(...)  });

Comment: @eeXBee thanks for your answer. I'm not sure this will work, look I added an example for div's name. I need a change() for each div

Comment: If it was up to me, I would use a foreach loop on divs.